# Compare strings when concatenated

Tags: python, python-itertools, string-comparison

I am comparing 2 input strings. This is simply achieved using a one-liner function I wrote as:

```
from itertools import product

def com_words(str1, str2):
    return sum([i==j for i,j in product(str1.split(), str2.split())])

print(com_words("BOST BREAD", "BOST BROWN BREAD"))
```

However, I also want to do human-like comparison when two words are concatenated. For example, the below code results in output as ZERO, whereas I want output as TWO:

```
print(com_words("BOSTBREAD", " BOST BROWN BREAD"))
```

Except brute-force method, I am unable to create a practical and fast algorithm. Pl help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this do?

```
from itertools import product

def com_words(str1, str2):
    return sum([(i in j) or (j in i) for i,j in product(str1.split(), str2.split())])

print(com_words("BOSTBREAD", "BOST BROWN BREAD"))
```

Comment: Thanks. That was crisp code. The only exception to your answer is when one word is already a subset of another. For example, the below should yield ZERO but yields TWO:

print(com_words("MIK MIKHAIL", "MINXMIKHAIL"))

Comment: Shouldn't it be at least 1 because "MINXMIKHAIL" has both "MIK" and "MIKHAIL" in it?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
def com_words(str1, str2):
    return sum([word in str1 for word in str2.split()])


print(com_words("BOSTBREAD", " BOST BROWN BREAD"))
```